# ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'

Tags: mysql, centos

when importing the db i am getting `ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'`

is there a way to fix this or a workaround for this.

i am using mysql 8.0.17 on centos 8

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode has been removed in [mysql8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)

Use `CREATE USER ...` and `GRANT ..` as separate sql statements and you won't need the no longer existing `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` sql_mode.